# Alto saxophone fingering for notes written below the staff

Tags: notation, fingering, saxophone, instrument-range, enharmonics

I am a beginner on the alto saxophone. I understand the fingering for playing notes on the staff but I do not understand the fingering for playing notes below the staff.  Sometimes there are two extra lines below the five line staff and notes are written on those lines and spaces.  What fingering do I use to get those notes?

Answer (score 2):

Just one line beneath the stave  I think.  Saxophones go down to a written Bb.  For which the fingering, logically enough, is 'everything closed'.

(Yes, it could be written as A#, which would be two lines below. Not sure why the chart includes lots of enharmonics but not that one.)

[image]

Chart from https://www.reedmusic.com/wp-content/uploads/Alto-Tenor-Saxophone-Fingering-Chart1.jpg

Comment: Is the note at two lines below the staff an A# by any chance? I was once a bit confused by a low B# in the pedal line in an organ piece, because the pedals only go down to C.

Comment: Also note that all the notes below the staff (except C Natural) use the keys by your left pinkie.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a teacher? Have you tried searching for fingering charts (one such chart is provided as a picture in an answer to this question)? [This](https://www.wfg.woodwind.org/sax/sax_alt_1.html) site is a great resource. I am really surprised your teacher didn't show you the respective fingerings during your first lesson. Saxes are notorious for having a crappy low range, and one of the first "checks" performed on a new instrument is playing all notes below C4. The low end is actually the easiest. Wait till you get above the top ledger line and into altissimo :)

Try using a mnemonic for memorising the notes at first. Or even write note names next to them in the beginning (I did). The most famous mnemonic is FACE (for notes between ledger lines) and Every Good Boy Deserves Fruit for the ledger lines themselves. The rest is counted downwards/upwards from those and gets memorised by itself in time.

Comment: Incidentally, I've heard hundreds of other mnemonics for the lines (Every Good Boy Does Fine, Every Green Boat Does Float, etc...)

Comment: @user45266, true. There's even a few "adult" versions...